# Use of full stop in CV

Tags: punctuation

In my CV, I have following type of information.

1. > Gave a talk on "Tits System, Monomial Matrices and BN pairs" as a part of ’Late Night
   >   Seminar Series’ in IISER Mohali
2. > Attended a Workshop on ’Hyperbolic Knot Theory’ oraganised at IISER Pune from 7
   >   December to 17 December 2015

Should I add a full stop at the end? My instincts says yes becasue although it is written in bullet points format, they are complete sentences.

Comment: Items in a list are not considered sentences unless they are explicitly complete grammatical sentences. You do not use a period at the end of such items.

Comment: Complete indicative sentences include a subject.

Comment: These sure are items of a list, but are way too long. -_- They look like sentences instead, where the subject is *implied* maybe. Can that happen?

Comment: A CV is neither every-day English, nor quite a list… which almost justifies ODO's laxity. It also means you should first try to find out whether your target or profession has an accepted style and if not, find your own and stick to it, remembering that here, "find your own" might mean choose from extant guides.

Answer (score 3):

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/bullet-points):

> 3. If the text following the bullet point is a complete sentence, it should begin with a capital letter, while a period at the end is technically required but is not absolutely essential.

Seeing as your sentences don't have a subject (you don't explicitly state that it is you who is doing those things - in a CV this is implied anyway), I might suggest that you don't need to.

Also, you have a typo in the second point: *organised* not *oraganised*.

Comment: What on earth does 'is technically required but is not absolutely essential' mean? The punctuation police will only shoot to wound?

Comment: Typo in CV: "Held at" might sound better.

Comment: It's not hedging (downtoning what would otherwise be a strict rule to a rule-of-thumb') here, it's saying 'this is necessary but not necessary'.  Contradiction in terms. What's needed is 'If the text following the bullet point is a complete sentence, it should begin with a capital letter, while a period at the end is preferred by traditionalists but is not absolutely essential.' A pity; ODO is usually good. // A good find, despite this. Though there is probably conflicting style advice elsewhere.

Comment: It is also not a grammar rule. It is punctuation.